# Transfer custom shape to openGL

Tags: opengl, vectorization, vector-graphics

I have problem with idea, how to add custom shape in to OPENGL.

I have image with custom shape like this: 
http://www.coloringpagebook.com/chicken-simple-shapes-coloring-pages/

I want to create vector image from this image and then put this vector image in to openGL to create shape.

What tools should I use to get info of the curves that then I can use in open GL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/) is a Free vectorization program.